# Fatal error: Class 'http\Client' not found in "../../.." using Docker Image

Tags: php, docker, debian-jessie

I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'http\Client' not found in /var/www/html/scripts/collections_getter_controller.php on line 46
```

The problem is the script "collections_getter_controler" is an include from two different scripts. When I exec the first one no error is prompted; however, when I exec the second one the error appears.

First script:

```
<?php
require "predis/autoload.php";
include "collections_getter_controller.php";
include "metadata_getter_controller.php";
include "bits_getter_controller.php";
include "invertedIndex.php";
Predis\Autoloader::register();

try {
    $redis = new Predis\Client();
.
.
.
```

The second script:

```
<?php
include "collections_getter_controller.php";
include "bits_getter_controller.php";

$itemIds = getCollectionitemIds('6');
.
.
.
```

As you can see in both cases the first include is "collections_getter_controller", so I can not identify what can be the problem because it's loaded in the first script but not the second.

Also, I should mention, I'm working on a Docker Image which is

```
FROM php:5.6.34-apache-jessie
```

**EDIT**

Following *ceejayoz* comment I'm adding the part of "collections_getter_controler" in which http\Client is used

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('../scripts/getter_config.xml');

# Here goes more code not related to the question

function getJSONCollections($id_req, $i){
    set_time_limit(0);
    $client = new http\Client;
    $request = new http\Client\Request;
    switch ($i) {
        case '1':
            $request->setRequestUrl((string)$GLOBALS['xml']->request->request_url.'/collections/'.$id_req);
            break;
        case '2':
            $request->setRequestUrl((string)$GLOBALS['xml']->request->request_url.'/collections/'.$id_req.'/items');
            break;
        default:
            $request->setRequestUrl((string)$GLOBALS['xml']->request->request_url.'/collections/'.$id_req);
            break;
    }
    $request->setRequestMethod((string)$GLOBALS['xml']->request->request_method);
    $request->setHeaders(array(
      'postman-token' => (string)$GLOBALS['xml']->request->header_token,
      'cache-control' => (string)$GLOBALS['xml']->request->header_cache,
      'authorization' => (string)$GLOBALS['xml']->request->header_auth
    ));

    $client->enqueue($request)->send();
    $response = $client->getResponse();
    return $response->getBody();
```

Comment: Presumably, `getCollectionitemIds` uses the `http\Client` class somehow. Can you show us what that function does?

Comment: @ceejayoz There is the update to the question

Comment: Where does the `http\Client` class come from? Is it your code? A library you're loading?

Comment: The problem there is that I was just given the Scripts and requested to build the Docker Image to run them. There is not any http\Client Code or Library mentioned by the author of the script

Comment: It's really hard to say without the entire codebase. The `http\Client` stuff looks like an older version of Guzzle (http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/). These days, it'd be installed with Composer and you'd be using the Composer autoloader for everything, but this code may predate that approach.

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz. I'll contact the code author for more details and I'll take into account your comment